# Attending Non-Jewish funerals

Tags: halacha, gentiles, funeral-burial-levaya

Is it permissible to attend a "wake" with a an open casket for a non-Jew held in a funeral home, not a church?

Comment: Good question! You might want to consider editing into it why you think that doing so might possibly be a problem? (Is it the presence of the deceased in an open casket? Is the recitation of prayers? Is it the seating arrangements? etc)

Comment: FWIW, I have heard that a wake is somewhat similar (in form) to a shiv'a call, except that the body is still present (eg. unburied). This is from the explanation that אמי מוריתי שת”י gave me when I was younger and enquired on the subject.

Comment: Please define a "wake" in th body of the question as I have heard different explanations as to wake goes on their.

Comment: @sabbahillel, see my comment. The guf is there, but otherwise, it's got almost all of the trappings of a shiva call (less any Torah)

Comment: related: [Is one allowed to attend a wake for a Jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93274/is-one-allowed-to-attend-a-wake-for-a-jew/93284#93284)

Answer (score 7):

Rav Elchanan Lewis [answers](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=2035) your question saying,

> A Jew can enter a non Jewish cemetery and attend a non Jewish funeral.
>   (see Bava Metziah 114a) The only prohibition is to enter a church if
>   the ceremony takes place there.

See [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=361) for a discussion of a Kohen attending such a funeral/wake.

Comment: What if it involves a Christian eulogy or the like?